# SpresenseのピンをArduinoIDEで活性化する方法を教えてください

Tags: spresense

基本的な質問で大変恐縮ですが、SpresenseのD05ピンをArduinoIDEで制御する方法を教えて下さい。
下記コードでは宣言されてなくエラーになって困っております。D05ではなくPWM1でも同じエラーになります。

```c
void setup() {
  pinMode(D05, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(D05, LOW);
}
```

下記がエラーです。

```
"D05" was not declared in this scope
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
Arduinoはピン番号でdefineするというお作法を理解しておりませんでした。下記で動きました。

```c
#define D05 5

void setup() {
    pinMode(D05, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(D05, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Arduinoでは直値(5)を、SpresenseではPIN番号の定義(PIN_D05)が使える様です。今回の場合PIN_D05をお使いいただくとよいと思います。